Exponential equation with two pairs of bases
On my level, we usually solve exponential equations like $a^m=a^n$ by comparing the exponents: $m=n$.
Let's say I have an equation: $$a^m*b^n=a^p*b^q$$
Is it then true that $m=p$ and $n=q$? Why or why not?
(this question came up when solving $15^{2x+4} = 3^{3x} · 5^{4x−4}$)

Welcome on MSE! If $a=2$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$, then $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$ satisfy $m+n/2=p+q/2$, one solution is $(m,n,p,q)=(2,2,1,4)$ for example. If $a$ and $b$ are comprime integers, and the exponents are integers, then you get $m=p$ and $n=q$ by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Maybe tell us if you have conditions on your problem.

It is certainly not the case that the only solutions have $m=p$ and $n=q$.
Consider that $a^m b^n = a^p b^q$ can be rewritten as $e^{m \ln(a) + n \ln(b)} = e^{p \ln(a) + q \ln(b)}$. Taking the logarithm of both sides gets us $m \ln(a) + n \ln(b) = p \ln(a) + q \ln(b)$, a single linear equation in four variables, so the solution space is three-dimensional, i.e. $m$ is only uniquely determined by a choice of $n$, $p$, and $q$.
